# Drawing a 'bullseye' in HTML5 Canvas using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm struggling a bit to get this to work. I have a 'Canvas' element on my web page, and I need to 'draw' filled circles within each other. I need to use a loop to draw the pattern, alternating between red and blue filled circles. It will use the initial band width value of 25. It will repeat the loop as long as the current radius is greater than 0. It will use a slider to control the band width. The slider has a minimum value of 5,
maximum value of 50 with step 5, and current value as 25. As the value of
the slider changes, it draws the pattern with the current bandwidth. I can make this work with gradients, but that does not do what I need it to do and it does not look right. Here is what I have so far:

```js
var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

    
win.onload = init;

    
// canvas and context variables
    
   
var context;

    
// center of the pattern
    
var centerX, centerY;


    
function init() {
        
            
canvas = doc.getElementById("canvas");
            
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            
centerX = canvas.width / 2;
            
centerY = canvas.height / 2;
            
            
// draw the initial pattern
            
//drawPattern();
    }


    
// called whenever the slider value changes
    
function drawPattern() {
   
var canvas;
      
// clear the drawing area
        
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        
// get the current radius
        
var radius = doc.getElementById("radius").value;

        
// set fill color to red
        
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


const colors = ['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F'];
const outerRadius = 100;
let bandSize = 10; // this would be where you put the value for your slider

for (let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length) {
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
    }

    
return {
        drawPattern: drawPattern
    };

})
(window, document);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="bullsEye.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <label for="bandwidth">BandWidth:</label>

  <input type="range" id="radius" min="5" max="50" step="5" value="25" oninput="sliderModule.drawPattern()" />
</body>

</html>
```

```
var sliderModule = (function(win, doc) {

win.onload = init;

// canvas and context variables
var canvas;
var context;

// center of the pattern
var centerX, centerY;


function init() {

        canvas = doc.getElementById("testCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        centerX = canvas.width / 2;
        centerY = canvas.height / 2;

        // draw the initial pattern
        drawPattern();
}


// called whenever the slider value changes
function drawPattern() {
    // clear the drawing area
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // get the current radius
    var radius = doc.getElementById("radius").value;

    // set fill color to red
    context.fillStyle = '#FF0000';

    // draw the pattern
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
}

return {
    drawPattern: drawPattern
};

})(window, document);
```

Comment: `var canvas = document.getElementById("bullseyeCanvas");` just confused as to why you are calling this ID. Wouldn't you need to call the `radius` ID? You're taking a non-integer value and dividing it.

Comment: 'radius' is the slider, not the canvas. The slider needs to alter the drawing.

Comment: Can you [also provide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) your `sliderModule.drawPattern()` code, or does it not exist?

Comment: Well that's embarassing. I didn't even think to look for code for that. I added it to my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet doesn't quite work as provided, but given a value for your slider, you'll just reduce radius and loop while radius is greater than 0.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

const colors = ['#F00', '#0F0', '#00F'];
const outerRadius = 100;
let bandSize = 10; // this would be where you put the value for your slider

for (let r = outerRadius, colorIndex = 0; r > 0; r -= bandSize, colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % colors.length) {
  ctx.fillStyle = colors[colorIndex];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<canvas />
```

What you're missing is the loop which would change. To control the colors, I made an array, and in addition to changing my radius each for-loop iterator, I also change the `colorIndex`.

I use `(colorIndex + 1) % colorIndex.length` so it'll loop through each of them and not go beyond the index (it'll count `0`, `1`, `2`, and back to `0`). You can change or add colors to the array.

Comment: I replaced my JS file with this and it only shows the slider now. Did I miss something?

Comment: My code just does the drawing. You probably want to drop it into your `drawPattern` function, then replace the `bandSize` value with the value coming from your slider.

Comment: I put your code into the drawPattern and it still doesn't draw. I updated the code above. Any idea what I missed?

Comment: Can you edit your question instead of my answer with the code you've got and I can take a look? Add it below your original question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I was editing my own snippet. It's updated above.

Comment: First up, you'll need to combine our variables properly. You can't just copy-and-paste what I gave you blindly, because I didn't write code that was 100% compatible with yours. I just gave you an example of the approach.